# Crear API con JWT en NET Core conectándose a MySQL

Tags: c#, jwt

he seguido algunos tutoriales en internet para crear una ApiMvc segura con JWT. La mayoría usa SQLServer pero yo quiero usar Mysql. Igualmente es la primera vez que lo intento:
Tengo mi archivo startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Text;
using WebApiSegura.Models;
namespace WebApiSegura
{
    public class Startup
    {
      

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
     

        public object UseMvcWithDefaultRoute { get; private set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

         services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
             {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                 {
                     ValidateIssuer = true,
                     ValidateAudience = true,
                     ValidateLifetime = true,
                     ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                     ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                     ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                     IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                         Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:ClaveSecreta"])
                     )
                 };
             });
            services.AddTransient<MySqlConnection>(_ => new MySqlConnection(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default"]));
            services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        
        }
    

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        [System.Obsolete]
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseHsts();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            // AÑADIMOS EL MIDDLEWARE DE AUTENTICACIÓN
            // DE USUARIOS AL PIPELINE DE ASP.NET CORE
            app.UseAuthentication();

           app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Luego appsettings.json:

```
{  

    "JWT": {
      "Audience": "localhost/api",
      "ClaveSecreta": "OLAh6Yh5KwNFvOqgltw7",
      "Issuer": "localhost"
    },
 
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=localhost;user=root;password=;database=apisegura"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

ApplicationDBContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApiSegura.Controllers;
using WebApiSegura.Models;

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Pais> Pais { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pais>().HasData(
            new Pais { Nombre = "España", Habitantes = 46000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Alemania", Habitantes = 83000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Francia", Habitantes = 65000000 },
            new Pais { Nombre = "Italia", Habitantes = 61000000 }
            );
    }
}
```

Y no se que me estaria faltando para que termine de andar, tengo la siguiente estructura de proyecto(compila perfecto y se abre el navegador mostrando las temperaturas)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir no logro generar el token. Cuando llamo a https://localhost:44355/api/login en POSTMAN me devuelve:404 Not Found.

Aqui esta el codigo de LoginController.cs:

````
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApiSegura.Models;
using WebApiSegura.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Claims;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    // TRAEMOS EL OBJETO DE CONFIGURACIÓN (appsettings.json)
    // MEDIANTE INYECCIÓN DE DEPENDENCIAS.
    public LoginController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    // POST: api/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(UsuarioLogin usuarioLogin)
    {
        var _userInfo = AutenticarUsuarioAsync(usuarioLogin.Usuario, usuarioLogin.Password);
        if (_userInfo != null)
        {
            return Ok(new { token = GenerarTokenJWT(_userInfo) });
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }

    private object GenerarTokenJWT(Task userInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private Task AutenticarUsuarioAsync(object usuario, object password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // COMPROBAMOS SI EL USUARIO EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS 
    private UsuarioInfo AutenticarUsuario(string usuario, string password)
    {
        // AQUÍ LA LÓGICA DE AUTENTICACIÓN //

        // Supondremos que el Usuario existe en la Base de Datos.
        // Retornamos un objeto del tipo UsuarioInfo, con toda
        // la información del usuario necesaria para el Token.
        return new UsuarioInfo()
        {
            // Id del Usuario en el Sistema de Información (BD)
            Id = new Guid("B5D233F0-6EC2-4950-8CD7-F44D16EC878F"),
            Nombre = "root",
            Apellidos = "Apellidos Usuario",
            Email = "email.usuario@dominio.com",
            Rol = "Administrador"
        };

        // Supondremos que el Usuario NO existe en la Base de Datos.
        // Retornamos NULL.
        //return null;
    }

    // GENERAMOS EL TOKEN CON LA INFORMACIÓN DEL USUARIO
    private string GenerarTokenJWT(UsuarioInfo usuarioInfo)
    {
        // CREAMOS EL HEADER //
        var _symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWT:ClaveSecreta"])
            );
        var _signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
                _symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
            );
        var _Header = new JwtHeader(_signingCredentials);

        // CREAMOS LOS CLAIMS //
        var _Claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, usuarioInfo.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim("nombre", usuarioInfo.Nombre),
                new Claim("apellidos", usuarioInfo.Apellidos),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, usuarioInfo.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, usuarioInfo.Rol)
            };

        // CREAMOS EL PAYLOAD //
        var _Payload = new JwtPayload(
                issuer: configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                audience: configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                claims: _Claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                // Exipra a la 24 horas.
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
            );

        // GENERAMOS EL TOKEN //
        var _Token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _Header,
                _Payload
            );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(_Token);
    }
}```
````

Comment: te faltaria mostrarnos el controller donde esta la accion Login

Comment: Listo ahi edite y coloque el codigo de LoginController.cs

Comment: `api/login/login`

Comment: -1. No soy muy fan de esta pregunta. OP sí nos proveyó de código que en otra ocasión hubiese sido relevante, SIN EMBARGO, su problema era un 404, y debió comenzar por ahí. No es un problema de EFCore, JWT, MySQL, etc. Asumió que era un problema en la configuración del proyecto como tal, cuando era, a todas luces, un error en la url que estaba utilizando en Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En MVC, las rutas van definidas como:

```
Controller/Action
```

Por lo tanto, cuando entras a:

```
https://localhost:44355/api/login
```

Esto se traduce como:

```
API/[Controller]
```

Lo que buscas es llegar a un action, por lo tanto:

```
API/Login/login
```

Comment: Ok gracias amigo. Se soluciono como comentas

Comment: Esto te será de ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: Gracias amigo. Voy a ver el código fuente y el vídeo.

Comment: Un placer colaborar con la nueva generación de desarrolladores, especialmente en C# y ASP Net Core :D Ese video es la crema y nata de lo que fue una serie de curos de la Microsoft Virtual Academy (MVA) de 27 horas aprox, resumidos en 4 horas 4 minutos 4 segundos.